# How do I hide a column from a DT table output?

Tags: r, dt

The DT package shows the following code [example](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html) to conditionally format a table.

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)

df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))

datatable(df) %>% formatStyle(
    'V1', 'V6',
    backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow'))
)
```

How can I hide the `V6` column from the final output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "**columnDefs**" option within **datatable()** function. This will make the V6 column hidden from view in the final output. You must create a list of options for "columnDefs" (visibile=() which is logical option  & targets() indicating column index) and therefore for the **datatable()** function to determine the visibility of the columns:

```
library(DT)
library(tidyverse)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(matrix(round(rnorm(50), 3), 10), 
sample(0:1, 10, TRUE)))

# create DT table
datatable(df
, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, 
targets=c(6))))) %>% 
  formatStyle('V1','V6', backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(0, 1), c('gray', 'yellow')))
```

[image]